# Docker Compose - Spring boot - logback outside the container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, logback

I have tried writing the log files outside the container, but it is getting failed. I am using docker-compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
gateway-service:
        container_name: gateway-service
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: core-gateway/gateway/Dockerfile
        expose:
            - 8080
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        volumes: 
            - /usr/app/home/inspectionimage:/home/inspectionimage
            - /usr/app/home/staging:/home/staging
            - /usr/app/home/production:/home/production
        networks:
            - qa-network
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8
RUN rm -rf gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY core-gateway/gateway/target/gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
VOLUME "/home/production"
VOLUME "/home/staging"
CMD ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=staging","gateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

**logback-spring.xml**

```
<appender name="prod-file"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/home/production/log-gateway-prod.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/home/production/log-gateway.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

when running docker compose command getting error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
gateway-service       | ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[prod-file] - openFile(/home/production/log-gateway-prod.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/production/log-gateway-prod.log (Permission denied)
```

I have provided necessary folder permission in CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the sestatus in CentOS 7. It worked.

```
setenforce 0
```

Changed the status from enforce to permissive